# Javascript objects like functions

Tags: javascript, dexie

Why can't I access the "inner" functions of this object? I feel like this has worked before.

```
var OfflineStorage = (function () {

    function OfflineStorage() {
        var db = new Dexie("OfflineStorage");
        db.version(1).stores({
            articles: "ArtNo,Description,Unit"
        });
    }

    function getArticlesByArtNo(params) {
        var regex = new RegExp(params.search, "i");

        return db.articles
            .filter(function (article) { regex.test(article.ArtNo) })
            .toArray();
    }

    return OfflineStorage;

})();
```

And when I try to access this object like so, I get an error.

```
var offlinestorage = new OfflineStorage();
offlinestorage.getArticlesByArtNo(); <-- This throws an error 'is not a function'
```

Comment: Those functions are private local symbols inside the anonymous function. Those are not implicitly made visible as object properties under any circumstances. You can *explicitly* make `getArticlesByArtNo` visible by assigning it as a property of the `OfflineStorage` function you return.

Comment: No, this has not worked before. You probably had a `OfflineStorage.prototype.getArticlesByArtNo = function…` previously.

Comment: you can also put the function inside the constructor. `this.getArticlesByArtNo = function(params)....`

Comment: @Oriol: Interesting dupe target :-)

Comment: @Bergi One of the first results that appeared in my search. There are better depetargets, probably

Answer (score -1):

You have to return the functions you want to access from outside like this:

```
return {OfflineStorage:OfflineStorage, getArticlesByArtNo:getArticlesByArtNo};
```

Comment: That does not work for the call the OP has shown